# regular expression not matching mutiple results, when matching against a single line

Tags: c#, xml, regex

Anyone handy with regular expressions?..

I'm running the following RegEx:

```
<body>.*</body>
```

On the following text:

```
<text>initial text</text>
 <comment>
   <user>
     6
   </user>
   <date>
     635277984371174139
   </date>
   <body>
     Recorded clinical data: 0132.00 Managing director dawd
   </body>
 </comment>
 <comment>
   <user>
     6
   </user>
   <date>
     635277984559612059
   </date>
   <body>
     Recorded clinical data: 0132.00 Managing director ii
   </body>
 </comment>
 <comment>
   <type>
     Completed
   </type>
   <user>
     6
   </user>
   <date>
     635277984668163579
   </date>
   <body>
     kkk
   </body>
 </comment>
```

However, this only results in one match...I would expect 3 matches..does anyone have any idea why?

Comment: What language are you using?  Perl?  Javascript?  R?  ;)  You could edit the question and provide the language as a tag.  It might help get the exact answer.  (See my comment about using the `/g` flag on your regex)

Comment: You are not capturing anything, so if there is at least 1 occurrence, than it will return it.

Comment: Good point about capturing.  @user3320546, do you want to include the `body` tags in your results or just the "inner HTML"?

Comment: So, either `(<body>.*?</body>)` or `<body>(.*?)</body>`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help guys.   I've also added a c# tag.

Answer (score 3):

1. You shouldn't parse HTML with regex (unless trivial & constant snippets of HTML), you risk weird bugs: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#answer-1732454)
2. Your regex is failing because `*` is a *greedy* quantifier. It means it will "eat" as much as possible: this will match from the first `<body>` to the last one, including the inside ones. What you want is

   ```
   <body>.*?</body>
   ```

   The `?` makes the quantifier non-greedy, it will stop at the first match.
3. You should edit your question, as your HTML is currently non-readable.

Answer (score 1):

Your expression is greedy. `.*` will match everything till the end and then backtrack to the point where `<\/body>` is found.

You need to make your regex lazy, like this -

```
<body>.*?<\/body>
```

Demonstrated [here](http://regex101.com/r/dU0sY8)

Comment: +1  You may also need to add the global switch like this: `htmlString.match(/<body>.*?<\/body>/g);`  (This is javascript)

Comment: Yep, in the link that I've added, I am using a global flag(PHP), but since there was no mention of any language, didn't mention it.

Comment: Escaping `/` isn't useful unless you enclose your regex in forward slashes. You may want to show that in your regex: `/<body>.*?<\/body>/`